# What is the composition of a standard diluent buffer in a leptin ELISA kit?

Tags: biochemistry, elisa

I am trying to find the composition of the diluent buffer used for the dilution of a human leptin stock to be used in an ELISA assay. The manufacturer of the kit (https://www.thermofisher.com/elisa/product/Leptin-Human-ELISA-Kit/KAC2281) only indicates that the buffer contains 8mM of sodium azide, but I cannot find the precise composition of the buffer anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Simple reason: They want you to buy their buffer and not make it on your own.

Comment: Totally get that, but is there anybody who has found what those buffers usually contain?